# Javascript add html dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have the following html code:

```
    <!-- Small button group -->
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Small button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now I would like to add dropdown-items over javascript based on the parsing of a xml file. But I have completely no idea how to do it. I've tried the way how it is described here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp, but that was not working.

Comment: You are trying to add a new achieve based on the button?

Comment: Show the code that you made from the example, not a link to the example. Also mention the browser and version where it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you mean something like this? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using the mdb boostrap library, which offers the above mentioned code snippet and I would like to add dropdown-items to it.